# Outlook.com (Hotmail) paragraph spacing issue

Tags: html, css, email, signature

Well I am creating a HTML signature for the company I am working for so I investiagted a little bit and started coding it using inline styles and native html properties. I have not tested it using testing services like Litmus and is not probably an option because of budget limitations.

Here is what I've done:
    
 - Used MS Outlook 2007 to create an empty signature
    
 - Used Notepad ++ for editing
    
 - All my code have inline styles and native html properties so there are no css classes

Long story short, everythig is fine, but when i send a email to outlook.com(hotmail) I have this wierd spacing issue. It appears as almost everything inside my table (used for layout) is wraped in p tags with this peculiar styling. eg.

```
//These values are just for reference
line-height:143%;
margin:0 0 1.3pt 0;
```

To get rid of all the bugs I encountered while testing, I have done these steps:

I have set width and height in native html properties AND with inline css

Used

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

to force maximum HTML/CSS support

Used a known fix for spacing issue that didnt work

```
    <style>
      .ExternalClass p.ecxMsoNormal {
        line-height: 100% !important;
        margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
      }
    </style>
```

Tried to have a background in td, but didn't succeed in fixing this so I just made a pic 1px wide and streched it to needed width but the height stayed as it is to rech a stripe like effect.

I Wanted to stretch an image across the page with width set as 100% and its container td (and table) also set to 100% but it didnt work. Table and td streches acordingly but the image receives a fixed value of 32px out of thin air so I couldnt figure that out too.

So thats it, I hope some of you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: It seams everything is wraped in <p> and <span> tags. Is there any way to  make Outlook 2007/10 send clean emails instead of  wrapping everything in <p> and <span> tags. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main culprit here was MS Outlook (desktop application). It edits my html email before sending it to the destination and removes everything from head section it also adds its own styles and bunch of other rules.

Wraps almost everything in < p > and < span > tags and then sends the email. All email clients that have "noraml" rules for < p > tags look more or less OK but outlook.com that has that stupid formating for < p > tag (mentioned above) renders the mail disassembled and ugly.

So I used Mozilla Thunderbird for sending HTML email and got rid of all the problems I encountered.